# undefined field javascript loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, for-loop

I'm trying to use ajax with a form I'm working on, and to do so I am building a post string,
Which looks like this: field_name=field_value&field_name=field_value and so on..

I am having trouble with figuring out where "undefined" is coming from. Take a look at this screenshot

[image: undifined example]

If you look carefully, you'll see the loop I am using, outputs "undefinedemail=Emailpassword=Password" instead of "email=Email&password=Password"

Here is the stripped version of the form & javascript I am using:

```
<form id="signup_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" method="post">
<input name="email" type="text" value="Email"/>
<input name="password" type="text" value="Password"/>
<input name="email_confirm" type="text"  value="Confirm Email"/>
<input name="password_confirm" type="text" value="Confirm Password"/>
<input name="first_name" type="text" value="First Name"/>
<input name="country" type="text" value="Country"/>
<input name="birthday" type="text" value="Birthday DD/MM/YYYY"/>
<input name="last_name" type="text" value="Last Name"/>
<input name="city" type="text" value="City"/>
<input name="profession" type="text" value="Profession"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"><span>Male</span>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"><span>Female</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_type" value="User type" /><span>Checkbox</span>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="" id="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var post_string;
var input = document.forms["signup_form"].getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 

post_string += input[i].name + "=" + input[i].value;
if(i > 0 && i < input.length) { post_string += "&"; }

}
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Please post your JS code, not only the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you're declaring `post_string` as an undefined variable, instead of declaring it as an empty string e.g. `var post_string = ""`.

That means, for the first look-up of `post_string`, it's returning the undefined variable instead.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that for 3 hours straight. Thank you. Now that only thing left is to figure out why the "&" character is being added in the last buildup. Got any ideas?

Comment: @user1614199: Use `if (i < input.length-1)` if you are appending the `&` char after the values.

Comment: Just did, got the same answer while playing with it. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: @user1614199 It's an easy thing to miss in JavaScript, dynamic typing can be your best friend and worst enemy.

Answer (score 2):

You did forget to initialize your accumulator variable with the empty string, so the first time you appended something it evaluated to `undefined`. Use

```
var post_string = "";
```